# How to pass input to batch command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a bat script which has block1 commands. I call the block1 like this

```
> mybat block1
```

and it executes the following

```
:BLOCK1
CALL some command InputString
goto :EOF
)
```

How can I change `InputString` so that it executes `AnotherInputString` or any other input

```
CALL some command AnotherInputString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If there is another command line argument, execute that argument as a command. Otherwise, continue."

```
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
    CALL some command %1
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```